# Addding variables to URL navigate to element UiPath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I added 2 variables (john, santa123) from input dialog box and then tried to navigate to a url from a browser scope.

Following is the navigate to URL.

> > "https://abcd.com/un=&username&pass=&password"

I'm unable to navigate to the input values. What am I doing wrong?

This navigates me to:

> > https://abcd.com/un=username&pw=pass

whereas I want it to navigate to

> > https://abcd.com/un=john&pw=santa123

Kindly point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the workflow, I would guess you have not broken out of your string and concatenated your variables when trying to navigate to the URL.

You have done the following in the browser URL property:

`"https://abcd.com/un=username&pw=pass"`

When you should have done this:

`"https://abcd.com/un="+username+"&pw="+pass`

Here is an example workflow I built to demonstrate this in practice:

[image]

Comment: I am new to uipath development. What I noticed from your screenshot was that I made a rookie mistake of not having output in those variables. Thanks for your answer, it did help me. Marking your answer as my answer. Cheers and happy holidays!

Comment: You could also use the Assert activity to save the new temporary string to a variable if you need it later again.